# What happens when clang-built program links against both libomp and libgomp?

Tags: c++, c, clang, openmp

I have a C/C++ program with various dependencies that come from my Linux distribution.

Some of the dependencies are linked with GCC's OpenMP library `libgomp.so`.

My program itself has its code compiled with clang's `-fopenmp` and linked with LLVM's OpenMP library `libomp.so`.

This means that the program's `ldd -v` shows both `libgomp.so` and `libomp.so` as dependencies that will be loaded on startup.

While my program seems to start correctly, I'm concerned about what happens in this case, with 2 OpenMP runtime libraries linked:

- Will it cause incorrect results?
- Will it disable OpenMP parallelism in the dependent libraries that use `libgomp`?
- Something else?

Thanks!

---

(Note that it is currently not possible to tell clang to just use GCC's `libgomp`; while there's a flag `-fopenmp=libgomp` that, it simply does nothing, disabling OpenMP, see https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227438#c2 and https://reviews.llvm.org/D2841)).

(This question is similar to [Can/should libiomp5 and libgomp mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548880/can-should-libiomp5-and-libgomp-mix) which is about mixing Intel+GCC OpenMP, but that says nothing about clang+GCC.)

Comment: To answer this question one needs to know two things: 1) How shared library linking works, and 2) whether or not the two shared libraries export any symbols in common. Although the first one is not something that can be explained in just a paragraph or two on Stackoverflow, it should be possible to determine the second one, with just a little bit of digging. Have you tried to pull all exported symbols from both libraries, using binutils, and compare them?

Comment: I would  think in general as long as symbols representing exported functions, or variables, _are unique_ between the two libraries, _and_ you are careful to limit invocation of  functionality from only one of the two libraries, you should be okay.  Complications will occur If there are naming conflicts between the two libraries.  What those complications are will depend on the implementation of your linker.

Comment: You should really avoid having both in your program. This is a source a many sneaky bugs. Yes this can cause incorrect results and even crash regarding how libraries are used and mixed. No it should not "disable OpenMP parallelism" because the libraries do not interact well with each other. It typically also cause more thread to be created and in some rare case (eg. nesting), an over-subscription of ready threads which is very bad for performance. If you know exactly what is the target OpenMP codes used for each case, then please share them. It can be safe in specific cases but not in general.

Comment: AFAIK libiomp and libomp use mostly the same implementation of so I expect them to behave the same.

Comment: @ryyker OpenMP specifies several runtime functions. For example, `omp_get_num_threads`. Such functions are (likely) implemented differently in the Clang runtime and the one of GCC. The generated code from OpenMP pragmas uses internal low-level functions that all have a prefix (eg. KMP and GOMP) so they cannot conflit between runtimes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am generally familiar with shared library linking and symbol conflicts, but unsure about OpenMP, which is more than just a shared library as it has deep ties into the compilers themselves.

Comment: As far as linking issues go, they are governed by exported symbols, and nothing else. It is true that there could be a conflict not related to symbol clashes. However, checking for symbol clashes will be the first step. If there are clashing symbols, it's game over. No need to proceed any further.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah, yes, I have already checked that my program links, and loads correctly at run-time, with both `.so`s linked in. So any issue that can be obviously traced to "can't load these two `.so`s with conflicting symbols" is not a problem for me. Instead I'm worried about any non-obvious cases, such as incorrect results at run-time, or ABI-incompatibility related crashes that won't be obvious to trace.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you. _"If you know exactly what is the target OpenMP codes used for each case, then please share them"_ -- unfortnately I cannot say that exactly, because the `libgomp`-using libraries are large open-source dependencies such as `suitesparse`, OpenCV and its recursive dependencies; which may not only have many OpenMP usages, but also may change across versions.

Comment: If the libraries use OpenMP internally and (the parallel parts) are always called from a sequential code, and the target libraries do not expose any OpenMP code from inlined functions, then I do not expect issues except a possible thread over-subscription. In such a case, the threads of the two runtimes should not be active simultaneously, but if they ever do that, then you can tweak that by setting `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` to `PASSIVE`. Sometimes, it can also cause threads binding issues (I got this issue on a non-mainstream platform though).

Comment: A safe solution is to rebuild all the dependencies using the same compiler (and so the same OpenMP implementation). It is not always easy nor even possible though. AFAIK, tools like Nix and Spack can help to mitigate dependencies issues in that case and avoid you to recompile/install everything manually (which is pretty cumbersome/time-consuming for large applications).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the added detail. Indeed I am already using Nix for my projects, and the contributor that opened the "[How should we build packages with clang and OpenMP?](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/79818)" issue :P The whole-world-recompile is tough though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that having more than one OpenMP runtime in a process is **not safe.**
The details are longer than will fit here, so I have written a blog post on CpuFun. See "[Is Mixing OpenMP® Runtimes Safe?](https://cpufun.substack.com/p/is-mixing-openmp-runtimes-safe)"

Comment: Really great stuff. Especially that you provided a concrete code example of what can go wrong!

Comment: Thanks, @nh2. From my POV the example is essential to prove (to myself, among others) that it can break!